# 2005 Kia sedona. Testing crankshaft pos sensor

Tags: electrical, starting, kia, crank-position-sensor

Some context:

We have a 2005 kia sedona. The car was working fine until it decided to quit. It was sitting around 40 - 50 minutes with the engine off. We thought that there could be a chance that maybe we ran out of gas or the fuel pressure waas to low. We put 5 gallons in it and no luck. The dash does light up and the relays in the motor compartment click but the starter dosen't run. We know that the battery isn't the issue and we can hear the fuel system. Someone in the parking lot for some reason had a code reader on then and they hooked it up to our car. It said that there was an issue with the crankshaft pos sensor.

Back to my question

I have all the tools that I would need to test it. The issue is that i cant find any information or diagrams on what to do to test it with a tool such as a multimeter. It would be very helpfull to get some information on what tests to go about.

If there is any other info that you need feel free to ask.

Comment: Crank sensor will not prevent the starter from running. How many miles on the Sedona? Possibly a bad starter motor.

Comment: Some Kia vehicles are know to have starting issues due to the anti-theft immobilizer. Try closing all doors, lock the vehicle, then unlock it. Now try starting. Did that work?

Comment: @Moab  Testing the starter motor is worth a shot but i also have heard of some cars disabling their startup if the crankshaft sensor isn't working. As for the anti theft i have read that and we have attempted to do something like that. I dont have acsess to the car right to try that though.

Comment: "heard of some cars disabling their startup if the crankshaft sensor isn't working" never heard of that, working on cars for 45 years.

Comment: Which engine do you have? There arent any meaningful tests you can do with a dvom on mre sensors other than check power and ground. You’d need a scope to check its output. I see a lot of these where the wiring harness has been rubbing and causing a short. This also wouldn’t cause a no crank situation.

Comment: @Moab Sorry, I just realized that I got that wrong. You are right that wouldn't stop it from cranking. It could be the anti-theft unit as the day after it died it started right up. I am still wondering what the issue is and if this is something that would happen again.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the sensor with a multimeter. (On the sensor) find the ground and the signal wire usually black (ground) blue (signal) put your multimeter to D.C. volts and see if you're getting voltage. Hopefully this helps.